# Disable FlipView inertia

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, flipview

Is there an easy way to stop the inertia effect of a FlipView when on the outer items?
I tried settings the FlipView ManipulationMode to TranslateY and TranslateRailsY only but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation=false`.
However, this only removes animation for keyboard, mouse and pen. You cannot disable it for touch.